# Minecraft Pocket Edition giving "Could not connect: Outdated client!" and "Unable to connect to world" error between version 1.16.201 and 1.16.40

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son has recently started playing Minecraft and asked if we could play together.  He has an Amazon Fire, but I have a PC.

I have found Bluestacks and am running (what I believe to be) Minecraft Pocket Edition on my PC.  He has a world on his Amazon Fire that I was able to join into and build with him.  However, recently I have not been able to.

He is currently running 1.16.201 (which appears to be a new update) on his Amazon Fire, but my PC is running 1.16.40.  Whenever I try to join his game I get the message, "Could not connect: Outdated client!".  I can not seem to find a way to "Update" my version (if my version is in fact the one that is outdated.)

In addition, we would LOVE to be able to create a world on my PC that HE will be able to join, but whenever he tries to join my world he gets the error message, "Unable to connect to world"

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 for Dad playing with son. :)

Answer (score 8):

If you look at the [MCBE version history](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_version_history), the outdated version is 1.16.40, the one on your PC.

Minecraft Bedrock Edition is considered a Microsoft Store app. So go to the Microsoft Store app on your PC and click on Downloads and Updates in the dropdown menu:

[image: Microsoft Store]

and that should allow you to update your game.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response!!

I didn't realize I could use the regular PC version and us be able to play together in the same world with him on his Amazon Fire.  So, the version I purchased was through Google Play.  I don't mind purchasing the PC version through Microsoft Store, but will have still have access to a world we have built on my PC through the Pocket Edition version?  Is there a way for me to copy that world and use it in the full PC version if I purchase through Microsoft Store?

Comment: @Will Does Google Play offer to update your Minecraft or not? I think the quickest updates are released to the Microsoft store first, if anywhere.

Comment: I could not find an update through Google Play until about an hour ago, when it finally changed from "Play" to "Update".  So, now, we are running on the same version.  Thanks again for the responses.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what version of Windows you're running, but The Microsoft Store edition of Minecraft Bedrock edition on Windows 10 should be fully compatible with the Kindle Fire edition for crossplay. You shouldn't need to use bluestacks or any other Android emulator if you just use the Windows 10 version.

If you don't want to use Windows 10 as your main OS and instead are still using Windows 7 or 8.1 (and you really, REALLY should be using Windows 10 on an internet-connected machine for various reasons), you could look into using a Virtual Machine to run Windows 10, though it's probably going to be slower.

Comment: Thank you as well for the super quick response!! As mentioned in my reply above, I didn't realize I could use the regular PC version and still be able to play in the same world as my son on his Amazon Fire. So, the version I purchased was through Google Play. I don't mind purchasing the PC version through Microsoft Store, but will I still have access to a world we have built on my PC through the Pocket Edition version? Is there a way for me to copy that world and use it in the full PC version if I purchase through Microsoft Store?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in other answers, you can get Minecraft Bedrock Edition on the Microsoft Store. As for sharing world files between devices, the path you're looking for would be `%localappdata%\MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\`, where you can find the path `games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds\`, which contains a folder for every world you have. You can move this folder around to share the world between all the devices you have (they will be local copies, if you're playing multiplayer, all the data is saved on the host). The game changed the folder names a quite a while back and now it's an encoded version of the world name you see in the game, but there should be a `levelname.txt` file containing the name you see in-game, and a `world_icon.jpeg` file (but not always) which is the thumbnail you see in-game, so you can choose one of those ways to identify the world you'd like to share.

I'm not familiar with the Amazon Fire, but given that it runs on an OS based on Android, I'd guess it's similar, if not the same. The game started saving game data internally by default a while back (in `/data/` partition, harder to access without rooting), but you can change it to save files externally on `/sdcard/`, where you can find a similar `minecraftWorlds` folder in `/sdcard/games/com.mojang/`. Just paste the world folder in there and restart the game, and it should show up. You can also copy world folders here and move it to your PC, this procedure works both ways.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Not all different versions are compatible to play on the same game. If we consider the `"Could not connect: Outdated client!"` message, your version might've been unable to play on the different version's world, and this actually happened to me. My friend was on 1.16.4 and I wanted to join their game until I realized I can't join because I was on 1.16.2, and had to eventually update.

TL;DR; Not all versions are compatible to play on the same game.